# "As of" message in Documentation history viewer has lowercase months

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, spelling

When viewing a previous version of Documentation, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/3719/include-javascript-code-in-html?asOf=2016080513441503), the month appears lowercase in the notice that it's a previous version:

[image]

For those who cannot see this image, it says:

> [image: Icon] You're viewing this topic as it existed aug 5 at 13:44.

The month is supposed to be uppercase in proper English grammar.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun find; the code responsible has been in use for ages, but **almost all** uses of *this particular* "render a relative date in a small amount of space" helper are on dev/admin/moderator pages, which is probably why it has never come up as a huge problem (especially on english.se ;p). Other public-facing examples:

- [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)
- [question / answer lists for users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell?tab=questions)

The reasoning for the lower-case here is almost certainly "to take the least possible horizontal space", but it is kinda wrong, and since we've added internationalization in a lot of places, we've had to do the work to make the layout friendlier to different-width text, so I *think* we can just remove to "lowercase" part without consequence. This would also make it a lot more consistent with other places where we leave the capitalization intact.

I'm going to tweak the code for now, but pending further discussion internally I *might* have to roll it back if there are genuine layout / stylistic reasons for the choice.